# VB.Net FileSystemWatcher - Multiple Folders and Multiple Files

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher, multiple-instances

I have a requirement of monitoring a root folder under which there are multiple folders and each folder containing multiple files (.csv) These files are being copied to a workstation from a server using some other third party tool. I have to monitor the workstation root's folder and as an when a .csv file is created or updated in any of the child folders, I have to write the .csv file data (updated or new) to a sql server database. While writing the data to the sql server, I need to capture the child folder name in which the .csv file was updated/created. This way I can have separate folder's data in one database file.

While running the program on the workstation pc, the application crashes without any specific error message. And since the app is run on a remote pc, I cannot debug the app to check which line is causing the crash. Below is the code:

```
Public Class FolderWatchAndProcess
Dim blnMonitorUpdated As Boolean = True
Dim blnMonitorCreated As Boolean = True
Dim blnShowMessage As Boolean
Dim strFullFileName As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFolderName As String
Private Delegate Sub updateLabel(ByVal newLabel As String)

Private Sub updateLabelHandler(ByVal labelText As String)
    lblMetNo.Text = labelText
End Sub

Private Sub ReadAndInsertCSVData()
' This routine checks for duplicates and inserts new records into the sql server database
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'lblMonitorPath.Text = "C:\RootFolder\"
    'btnStartWatching_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
    'Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub

Private Sub btnStartWatching_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartWatching.Click
    btnStartWatching.Text = "Stop Watching"
    Dim aFileWatcherInstance As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    For Each sMonitorFolder As String In lstFolders.Items
        If IO.Directory.Exists(sMonitorFolder) Then
            Dim oFileWatcher As FileSystemWatcher = New FileSystemWatcher
            oFileWatcher.Path = sMonitorFolder
            oFileWatcher.Filter = "*.CSV"
            If blnMonitorUpdated Then
                AddHandler oFileWatcher.Changed, AddressOf Me.FileSystemWatcherUpdated
            Else
                'RemoveHandler , AddressOf Me.FileSystemWatcherUpdated
            End If
            If blnMonitorCreated Then
                AddHandler oFileWatcher.Created, AddressOf Me.FileSystemWatcherCreated
            Else
                'RemoveHandler , AddressOf Me.FileSystemWatcherCreated
            End If
            oFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            aFileWatcherInstance.Add(oFileWatcher)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FileSystemWatcherCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
    strFullFileName = e.FullPath
    strFileName = Mid(e.Name, 3, Len(e.Name))
    strFolderName = strFileName.Split("_")(0)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New updateLabel(AddressOf updateLabelHandler)
        Me.BeginInvoke(d, New Object() {strFolderName})
    Else
        updateLabelHandler(strFolderName)
    End If
    ReadAndInsertCSVData()
End Sub

Private Sub FileSystemWatcherDeleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
    'A file has been deleted from the child directory.
End Sub

Private Sub FileSystemWatcherUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
    strFullFileName = e.FullPath
    strFileName = Mid(e.Name, 3, Len(e.Name))
    strFolderName = strFileName.Split("_")(0)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New updateLabel(AddressOf updateLabelHandler)
        Me.BeginInvoke(d, New Object() {strFolderName})
    Else
        updateLabelHandler(strFolderName)
    End If
    ReadAndInsertCSVData()
End Sub
```

End Class

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you add some try-catch block and log any error to event log? it is difficult to troubleshoot program crash without any clue.

Comment: i tried that and could not detect any errors while updating a few folders using copy paste. Could it be caused by the SQL server routine or is it being caused the third party sync tool since the file is being used during copying and might still be in use before completing the copy activity from the server.

Comment: In your application, be sure to subscribe to **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException** event and when it occurs, log the exception. Then add the exception you found to this question.

Comment: If you cannot get the error with try/catch just quickly install VS express, then you can debug it to find the issue.

Comment: @mr_w_snipes, i have included a try catch block, but cannot install vs express or any other ide since its the client's machine. Just wanted to know if the code above is correct on its own or can it be made much better with inclusion of threads/timers etc. Suggestion appreciated.

Comment: The crash window displays the following information:

Comment: Crash window shows:Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: AppFSW.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 55c7f9dd
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.34209
  Problem Signature 06: 534894cc
  Problem Signature 07: 4527
  Problem Signature 08: 1f4
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.IOException
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: I have managed to find the error using development mode debug. The error is The process cannot access the file 'C:\TargetRoot\Folder1\File1.CSV' because it is being used by another process.

How can the file which is being copied to the target folder be in use? Why does it not apply to other files that have already been copied to the target folder?

The error occurs on the line - Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(strFullFileName). This line is inside the ReadAndInsertCSVData routine

Comment: if you use a streamwriter or another routine you must make sure to close it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: I have managed to fix just about everything. However it seems the ReadAndInsertCSVData routine is being executed more than once. Did i miss something to terminate something since this app will have to keep running 24x7?

Answer (score 0):

the Changed event will fire multiple times:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx

probably you can use the IsFileLocked function that mention at here:

[I keep getting exception sometimes on System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<bool> how can i solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953418/i-keep-getting-exception-sometimes-on-system-threading-tasks-taskcompletionsourc)